# unable to install packages("caret") completely in R version 3.2.3

Tags: r, package

```
> require("caret")
  Loading required package: caret
  Loading required package: lattice
  Loading required package: ggplot2
  Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =      vI[[j]]) : 
   there is no package called ‘pbkrtest’
```

So I found that there is lack of "pbkrtest" then I tried to reinstall it.

```
> install.packages("pbkrtest")
 Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
 (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

 There is a binary version available but the source version is
 later:
     binary source needs_compilation
 pbkrtest  0.4-2  0.4-3             FALSE

 installing the source package ‘pbkrtest’

trying URL 'https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/src/contrib/pbkrtest_0.4-  3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 164415 bytes (160 KB)
downloaded 160 KB

* installing *source* package 'pbkrtest' ...
** package 'pbkrtest' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: replacing previous import by 'stats::sigma' when loading 'pbkrtest'
Error : object 'sigma' is not exported by 'namespace:stats'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pbkrtest'
* removing 'C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/pbkrtest'

The downloaded source packages are in 
    ‘C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk7mJT0\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"D:/R-3.2.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l     
"C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"   

  C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpk7mJT0/downloaded_packages/pbkrtest_0.4-  3.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("pbkrtest") :
installation of package ‘pbkrtest’ had non-zero exit status
```

It seems like that the installation keeps failing.
As a result, I couldn't use other code using caret packages.

Comment: I just downloaded r_release version on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html .  And I installed it manually then the problem seems solved...

Comment: There was a thread on Rhelp where this was explained: Search for Subject=  "Updating Package Fails: Help on How to Fix Needed"

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem as well on Windows 7. I did following steps in the sequence and it worked.
a) Make sure your R version is updated latest R release 3.2.3
b) The default sources seems to be installing Unix version. So I manually downloaded https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html for windows
c) Use manually install function from R menu to install the package.

Cheers,
Ratan

Answer (score 0):

1. Check version of R by typing `version` in your console.
   If version is **not** "**version.string R version 3.3.2**" or later then
2. Install new version of R from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/
3. Update R version using Tools => Global Options in RStudio.
4. install package using "`install.packages("caret")`" in your console.
5. do `require(caret)`.
6. test using `?createDataPartition`.