# R studio caret package pbkrtest

Tags: r, package, r-caret

I'm not able to load the caret package in R studio due to the missing of /dependecy on the 'pbkrtest' package. However, the pbkrtest package is not available in R studio Version 0.99.879 (for mac). I updated R studio and all packages already. Here is the error message:

[error message R Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYaKK.png)

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, this error keeps popping up very regularly. The solutions vary, but what usually solves it is to update R. Could you verify that you are running R 3.2.3? [Maybe try installing manually as suggested in the comments in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236629/unable-to-install-packagescaret-completely-in-r-version-3-2-3)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the message 'This is R 3.2.2' However I downloaded the latest update from the R Studio website. Where can I find R studio 3.2.3?

Comment: Ha, I edited the comment a bit too late, it seems :) RStudio is just an interface for R. You need to go to the R website and download a newer version of R itself. Just Google `download R`. Apparently 3.2.4 is already available, but 3.2.3 would also work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I already downloaded R 3.2.4. however R studio recons that it is version 3.2.2, how can I change this?

Comment: It should detect it automatically. Restarting RStudio should be enough. If not, you may want to follow the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656699/update-r-using-rstudio

Comment: Good to hear it worked. I reported it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186830/issues-installing-caret-package (which it is) in order to close the thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update R using RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656699/update-r-using-rstudio)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to upgrade R for whatever reason (for example if you are running a SQL Server in-database R), a solution to this problem for me was to install the pbkrtest package from source directly ([package version history](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pbkrtest/)). You can try different versions, but the one that worked for me was 0.4-4. You can install using the following command:

```
install.packages(path_to_file, lib=lib,repos = NULL, type="source")
```

where "path_to_file" is the location of your package with the package file name ending in .tar.gz likely and "lib" is the optional parameter for your R library -- if omitted the default will be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
#This should work!

remove.packages("caret")
#this will completely uninstall caret from your device
install.packages("caret")
```